# What does a sql-query in php on an empty table return?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following PHP script :

```
 <?php
       $all_threads=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM forum_threads WHERE category=$_GET[id]");

       if($all_threads){ ?>
            //Do something.
     <?php
       }
       else { ?>
            //Do something else
      <?php
       } ?>
```

The table forum_threads is empty, so the query should return 'false' according to the documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php and the 'else' block should get executed. However, strangely, the if-block is getting executed. How come?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will return a MySQL resource, not `FALSE` on 0 rows. It will return `FALSE` on a query error.

You can check `mysql_num_rows()` instead. It will be `0` if there were no rows returned.

You also have a SQL injection vulnerabilities. Escape the GET param with `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

If you can, just ditch `mysql_*()` and use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: `mysqli_` is another options to upgrade to from `mysql_`

Answer (score 2):

It won't return `false` because there is no error in your SQL statement, it's simply returning an empty result set because there are no matching records.